# Unmocking a mocked object in Django unit tests

Tags: django, mocking

I have several TestCase classes in my django application.   On some of them, I mock out a function which calls external resources by decorating the class with @mock.patch, which works great.   One TestCase in my test suite, let's call it B(), depends on that external resource so I don't want it mocked out and I don't add the decorator.   It looks something like this:

```
@mock.patch("myapp.external_resource_function", new=mock.MagicMock)
class A(TestCase):
    # tests here

class B(TestBase):
    # tests here which depend on external_resource_function
```

When I test B independently, things work as expected.   However, when I run both tests together, A runs first but the function is still mocked out in B.      How can I unmock that call?  I've tried reloading the module, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Patch has [start and stop methods](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html#start-and-stop). Based on what I can see from the code you have provided, I would remove the decorator and use the setUp and tearDown methods found in the link in your classes.

```
class A(TestCase):
  def setUp(self):
    self.patcher1 = patch('myapp.external_resource_function', new=mock.MagicMock)
    self.MockClass1 = self.patcher1.start()

  def tearDown(self):
    self.patcher1.stop()

  def test_something(self):
    ...

>>> A('test_something').run()
```

Comment: Thanks, start and stop is what I needed!

Comment: What if one test requires a mock, the other does not?  Is there no other way to do this than to patch/start/stop within each unit test?

Answer (score 1):

Great answer.  With regard to Ethereal's question, patch objects are pretty flexible in their use.

Here's one way to approach tests that require different patches.  You could still use setUp and tearDown, but not to do the patch.start/stop bit.

You start() the patches in each test and you use a finally clause to make sure they get stopped().

Patches also support Context Manager stuff so that's another option, not shown here.

```
class A(TestCase):
    patcher1 = patch('myapp.external_resource_function', new=mock.MagicMock)
    patcher2 = patch('myapp.something_else', new=mock.MagicMock)


    def test_something(self):

        li_patcher = [self.patcher1]
        for patcher in li_patcher:
            patcher.start()


        try:
            pass
        finally:
            for patcher in li_patcher:
                patcher.stop()


    def test_something_else(self):

        li_patcher = [self.patcher1, self.patcher2]
        for patcher in li_patcher:
            patcher.start()

        try:
            pass
        finally:
            for patcher in li_patcher:
                patcher.stop()
```